# Table View Controller code not getting invoked

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I've got an app with a Web View and a Table View. The Web View works fine, but the Table View does not seem to be invoking the `TableViewController.h` code when displaying. I think I missed a linking step somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out.

To clarify, I originally set up the project as a single view application but later added a Navigation controller and the Table View manually.

After I manually added the Table View to the storyboard, I created `TableViewController.h` and `TableViewController.m`, but I can't figure out how to link the code to the Table View in the story board.

Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: You added a table view or a tableViewController in the storyboard?

Comment: I think that rdelmar was asking whether you added a tableview to a plain view controller (in which case my answer might apply) or whether you added a tableview controller to your storyboard (in which Moxy's answer might apply). If you did the former, you have to set delegate and data source manually, but you did the latter, that's taken care of for you, so the likely problem is that your subclass might not have been specified. These are the two common problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the class of the controller you're using in the storyboard to be `TableViewController`

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was significantly easier than what I was thinking. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Two scenarios:

First, **if you added a tableview to a standard `UIViewController`** (i.e. you dragged a table view to your blank, standard view controller in Interface Builder and the .h for your view controller specifies that it is a subclass of `UIViewController`), then you have to specify the "data source" and "delegate" properties of your table view manually. Thus, you should make sure to configure the "data source" and "delegate" for your tableview to reference your view controller. You can do this in either Interface Builder (by selecting the tableview, going to the "Connections Inspector" in the far right panel, and then make sure you've specified the outlets for data source and delegate):

[image]

Or set [`dataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/dataSource) and [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/delegate) properties in your `UIViewController` subclass `viewDidLoad` code:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

In this scenario, you also want to ensure that you created a `IBOutlet` for your tableview, too.

---

Alternatively, **if you used a `UITableViewController`** (i.e. you removed the blank view controller and added your own table view controller into your storyboard in Interface Builder and have made sure that your view controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController`, not `UIViewController`), see [Moxy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13869645/1271826).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Moxy's solution indeed solved it for me.